# Automatically generate import module for dynamic loading .so library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I want link open source 3rdparty library as dynamically loaded shared library on Linux. It is need to allow use it as optional plugin. It is AWS-SDK for C++ library but it is not important for question and uses as example. I build .so library and could statically link it and use they API in my code. When i removed library dependency from link command and have got (as expected):

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.28
CMakeFiles/ed_core.dir/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp.o: In function `ed::amazons3client::(anonymous namespace)::AwsInit::AwsInit()':
  /devroot/develop/src/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp:61: undefined reference to `Aws::InitAPI(Aws::SDKOptions const&)'
  /devroot/develop/src/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp:62: undefined reference to `Aws::Utils::Logging::InitializeAWSLogging(std::shared_ptr<Aws::Utils::Logging::LogSystemInterface> const&)'
CMakeFiles/ed_core.dir/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp.o: In function `ed::amazons3client::(anonymous namespace)::AwsInit::~AwsInit()':
  /devroot/develop/src/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp:68: undefined reference to `Aws::Utils::Logging::ShutdownAWSLogging()'
  /devroot/develop/src/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp:69: undefined reference to `Aws::ShutdownAPI(Aws::SDKOptions const&)'
CMakeFiles/ed_core.dir/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp.o: In function `ed::amazons3client::MultipartSink::init[abi:cxx11]()':
  /devroot/develop/src/core/AmazonS3Client.cpp:550: undefined reference to `Aws::S3::Model::CreateMultipartUploadRequest::CreateMultipartUploadRequest()'
....
```

So now i need manually write import module where will be loading .so via dlopen(), declared pointers to needed symbols, initialization such symbols via dsym() and redirects calls to symbols via stubs for undefined functions.

Is it any way to do it differently? LD knows what symbols needed. GCC knows theirs declaration. Is it any way do connection on the fly or generate such import module automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin way to do this with GNU tools but generation of necessary boilerplate code (`dlopen`, `dlsym`, etc.) can be easily automated (see e.g. the [Implib.so project](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so)).

Comment: @slonma could you check if this answers your question?